# Python using lxml to write an xml file with system performance data

Tags: python, lxml, psutil

I am using the python modules `lxml` and `psutil` to record some system metrics to be placed in an XML file and copied to a remote server for parsing by php and displayed to a user.

However, lxml is giving me some trouble on pushing some variables, objects and such to the various parts of my XML.

For example:

```
import psutil, os, time, sys, platform
from lxml import etree

# This creates <metrics>
root = etree.Element('metrics')

# and <basic>, to display basic information about the server
child1 = etree.SubElement(root, 'basic')

# First system/hostname, so we know what machine this is
etree.SubElement(child1, "name").text = socket.gethostname()

# Then boot time, to get the time the system was booted.
etree.SubElement(child1, "boottime").text = psutil.boot_time()

# and process count, see how many processes are running.
etree.SubElement(child1, "proccount").text = len(psutil.pids())
```

The line to get the system hostname works.

However the next two lines to get boot time and process count error out, with:

```
>>> etree.SubElement(child1, "boottime").text = psutil.boot_time()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 921, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:41344)
 File "apihelpers.pxi", line 660, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:18894)
 File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1333, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:24601)
 TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'float'
>>> etree.SubElement(child1, "proccount").text = len(psutil.pids())
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 921, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:41344)
 File "apihelpers.pxi", line 660, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:18894)
 File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1333, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:24601)
 TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'int'
```

So, here's what my XML looks like as printed:

```
>>> print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
<metrics>
  <basic>
    <name>mercury</name>
    <boottime/>
    <proccount/>
  </basic>
</metrics>
```

So, is there anyway to push floats and ints to xml text like I need? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` field is expected to be unicode or str, not any other type (`boot_time` is `float`, and `len()` is int).
So just convert to string the non-string compliant elements:

```
# First system/hostname, so we know what machine this is
etree.SubElement(child1, "name").text = socket.gethostname() # nothing to do

# Then boot time, to get the time the system was booted.
etree.SubElement(child1, "boottime").text = str(psutil.boot_time())

# and process count, see how many processes are running.
etree.SubElement(child1, "proccount").text = str(len(psutil.pids()))
```

result:

```
b'<metrics>\n  <basic>\n    <name>JOTD64</name>\n    <boottime>1473903558.0</boottime>\n    <proccount>121</proccount>\n  </basic>\n</metrics>\n'
```

I suppose the library could do the `isinstance(str,x)` test or `str` conversion, but it was not designed that way (what if you want to display your floats with leading zeroes, truncated decimals...).
It operates faster if the lib assumes that everything is `str`, which it is most of the time.

Comment: Well....I was way overthinking the situation. Thanks for answering for my incompetence! cookie for you sir.